# SQL Query to obtain number of tickets in a given month of a given year

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT ToText("CLSDDATE",'MMMM yyyy'),COUNT("PRIORITY") AS TotalPerMonthLow
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND YEAR("CLSDDATE") > '2012'
GROUP BY MONTH("CLSDDATE")
```

This works (except for the ToText, but the concept is there), but it groups together all of the tickets in all of the January's together. Ideally, this query would return a table that looks like this:

1. January 2012 - 103
2. February 2012 - 114
3. March 2012 - 121

...

37. January 2015 - 451
38. February 2015 - 472

etc.

This is going to be used to plot ticket fulfillment trends across our years of operation in a Crystal Report. It will be in a scatter plot, so I supposed the MonthYear column could just be 0-indexed from January 2012.

Comment: I see you got an answer that works for you. The problem with your original approach was that you needed to group by both year and month and that you must return aggregates on columns that aren't grouping columns.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat the same calculated field in GROUP BY

```
SELECT ToText("CLSDDATE",'MMMM yyyy'),COUNT("PRIORITY") AS TotalPerMonthLow
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND YEAR("CLSDDATE") > '2012'
GROUP BY ToText("CLSDDATE",'MMMM yyyy'), MONTH("CLSDDATE")
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using what I posted, but your post inspired it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Group By and Order By to enforce order:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(m,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-11-01',120),"CLSDDATE") AS MonthsFromNov2013,COUNT("PRIORITY") AS TotalPerMonthLow
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'Low - 3 Days'
AND ((YEAR("CLSDDATE") = '2013' AND MONTH("CLSDDATE") >= '11') OR YEAR("CLSDDATE") > '2013')
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(m,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-11-01',120),"CLSDDATE")
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(m,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-11-01',120),"CLSDDATE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by both year and month otherwise you'd lump Feb 2012, Feb 2013, Feb 2014 all together for example. `Month()` just returns a number from 1 to 12.

The other problem with your first approach was you tried to use the `CLSDDATE` column in the expression `ToText("CLSDDATE",'MMMM yyyy')`. After doing the grouping SQL now has more than one `CLSDDATE` value (more than one row per group) to use in evaluating that expression so it has not way to determine which one you wanted. (Other platforms like Sybase and MySQL will accept it but take a group value essentially at random.)

`ToText()` is not a SQL Server function (it's a Crystal formula function) but supposing that it were you could have used `ToText(MIN("CLSDDATE"),'MMMM yyyy')` instead. Newer versions of SQL Server do have `DATEFORMAT()` though.

You month index solution is probably perfect. Had you needed to reconstruct a real date value you could use an expression that evaluates to the first day of the month for the given month and year number as below.

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(
        mm,
        MONTH(CLSDDATE) - 1,
        DATEADD(
            yy,
            YEAR(CLSDDATE),
            CAST('20000101' AS DATETIME)
        )
    ),
    COUNT(PRIORITY) AS TotalPerMonthLow
FROM TRACKIT_DATA2.TrackItApp_1.vTASKS_BROWSE
WHERE PRIORITY = 'Low - 3 Days' AND YEAR(CLSDDATE) > '2012'
GROUP BY YEAR(CLSDDATE), MONTH(CLSDDATE)
```